# Await vs Task.WaitAll while openning SqlConnection - why does Await throw an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await

I had a simple async method to check if `SqlConnection` is closed and if it is - open it:

```
protected async Task EnsureConnectionOpenedAsync()
        {
            if (SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed && SqlTransaction == null)
            {
                await this.SqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            }
        }
```

At first it worked normally, but suddenly it started to throw an exception `"A task was cancelled"`. When I haven't changed anything that touches the `SqlConnection`! It just somehow stopped working adequately. But after I made another version of `EnsureConnectionOpened`:

```
protected Task EnsureConnectionOpened()
        {
            if (SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed && SqlTransaction == null)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(this.SqlConnection.OpenAsync());
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

everything started working OK again.

Why did it happen? The code where I call it:

```
protected virtual async Task<int?> UpdateAsync(string storedProcedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
        {
            try 
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, this.SqlConnection, this.SqlTransaction)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout
                };

                if (sqlParameters.IsInitializedAndFilled())
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameters)
                    {
                        if (sqlParameter.Value == null)
                        {
                            sqlParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
                        }
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
                    }
                }

                await this.EnsureConnectionOpenedAsync();
                await this.DeployStoredProcedure(storedProcedureName);

                return (int)await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.SqlConnection.Close();
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are very few uses for a method called `EnsureConnectionOpened` (`Async`) unless you're *sharing connection objects around*. This almost always ends badly. Almost always better to keep those objects local and just share the connection *string*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever got your point, this method is actually local and never used in other cllsses, I probably should make it private

Comment: @el_nektarin It's not about making it private. It's the fact that your connection should be a local variable, not a field or property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was very simple - the method which invoked the `UpdateAsync` command wasn't awaiting it (and wasn't marked as `async` respectively). So look carefully through your `async` code - you should await it everywhere you have to.